# who is issuing my UIKeyboardDidHideNotification?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotifications

I want to register to `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` that only my UIViewController is issuing.

When I do :

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:self];
```

I'm not getting any calls to `keyboardDidHide:` and when I do :

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

I'm getting calls from all the other view controller as well as my own.

How can I register to the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` raised only by a specific view controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no way to register for a UIKeyboardDidHideNotification coming from a specific controller.

If using UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, you could check if one of the UITextView inside your controller is the first responder.

Using UIKeyboardDidHideNotification I guess you need to use delegate methods for all your UITextView and save the last one that was edited. I don't think of any other alternative.

Else, if the issue is to perform the method called by UIKeyboardDidHideNotification only on the visible controller, the solution by @sviatoslav-yakymiv works well.

Comment: so in theory if i define a boolean on each view controller something like didIssueKeyboardHideNotification and set it to true after i call resignFirstResponder (or in my case setCancelsTouchesInView:YES ) and check for that boolean in every keyboardDidHide: implementation i should be able to know which one is it. right ?

Comment: Yes, it should work like that. Do not forget to reset the boolean to false at the end of keyboardDidHide:

Comment: cool, im setting your answer as correct, cuz it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Object for `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` is always `nil`. Try to add observer in `viewWillAppear` and remove in `viewDidDisapper` methods.